# Why is my Lazy<T> re-initializing every time I call Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, lazy-evaluation

I have a member of my controller

```
    private Lazy<MyCache> loadedComponentCache = new Lazy<MyCache>(() =>
    {
        MyCache instance = MyCacheb.Instance;
        instance.LoadStuffAsync().Wait();
        return instance;
    }, LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
```

that I'm using to lazy-call a long-running method `LoadAsync()` that will only need called if a certain API endpoint is hit after the user goes to the page.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetStuff()
    {
        var results = from component in loadedComponentCache.Value.All()
                      // ... 
    }
```

Any idea why it's re-loading every time the API endpoint is hit? My understanding is that an instance of my controller is created only when the user goes to the page and thus this will only be hit once per API call per user visiting the page.

Comment: A new instance of a controller is created for each request. So your `Lazy` is effectively recreated for each request.

Comment: @zaitsman Thanks. How can I make it initialize once per page visit?

Comment: what do you mean 'once per page visit'? Each request is a `page visit`. So you are doing that exactly...

Comment: probably @Questionaire uses "visit" as meaning "session". In this case, you'd need to add a (lazy) MyCache instance as a `Session` item

Comment: You have a stateless application, if you do not initialise it for every reqeust, how can you use `loadedComponentCache `. If you want to initialise it only once for the entire application life cycle you can make it singleton or static.

Answer (score 1):

You could make loadedComponentCache static but that's not ideal. If you are using an IoC container you could register it as a singleton. These long lived objects are generally to be avoided though if possible.

If you you truely need this long lived cache then you should probably consider using something like Redis which is designed and optimised for this sort of scenario and can be distributed across multiple nodes. https://redis.io/topics/introduction